# Rolling Year: Actual And Last Year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following fields:

1. Year
2. Category
3. Maker
4. Month
5. Month Number
6. Sales Volume
7. Sales
8. Date

[image]

So, I have in my dash a filter for "Month Number" and "Year":

[image]

My goal is to create two new measure; first with the `Rolling Year` that need to sum 12 months, ending in the moment that the user select in the mencioned filters. For example if y select `Year` 2021 and `Month` 01. The `Rolling Year` need to sum the sales of a selected category since 2020-02 to 2021-01 (thats mean always 12 months since a pivot month).

For thesecond is exactly the same, a measure called `Rolling Last Year`, it need to be a rolling sum too, but for the last period in order to compare. Taking the same example if I have the period 2020-02 to 2021-01. The `Rolling Last Year` for the last period should be 2019-02 to 2020-01.

I tried with this DAX code, that extracted from Microsoft page but without success:

```
Rolling Year =
CALCULATE (
SUMX ( Table, Table[Sales] ),
FILTER (
ALL (Table[Date] ),
AND (
Table[Date] <= MAX ( Table[Date] ),
DATEADD ( Table[Date], 12, MONTH ) > MAX ( Table[Date] ))))
```

I share you an extract of my base:

[image]

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the table and code you have shared, it is unclear from where the date filters are being applied. In case you have not done it, I strongly suggest to delete the [Month] and [Month Number] field from your Sales table and keep them in a separate Calendar table, from where the filters should be selected. Then, a simple tweak on you current formula should do the trick:

```
Rolling Year = 
CALCULATE (  
SUMX ( Table, Table[Sales] ),  
FILTER (  
ALL ('Calendar'[Date] ),  
AND (  
Table[Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),  
DATEADD ( 'Calendar'[Date], 12, MONTH ) > MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ))))
```

However you can try with this variation for the code, a little bit optimized so as not to scan your whole Sales table each time:

```
Rolling Year = 
VAR EndSelectedDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
VAR StartSelectedDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        ALL ( 'Calendar'[Year] ),
        'Calendar'[Year]
            = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Year] ) - 1
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table[Sales] ),
        ALL ( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] <= EndSelectedDate,
        'Calendar'[Date] > StartSelectedDate
)
```

Comment: But as far I understand with this formula I can not calculate since the date of selection, the sales of the 12 month ago . Also dont filter by category, right?